# Form submit using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need to submit the a form using Ajax with POST method.The code is as follows,

```
function persistPage(divID,url,method){ 
    var scriptId = "inlineScript_" + divID;
    var xmlRequest = getXMLHttpRequest();   
    xmlRequest.open("POST",url,true);
    xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    alert(xmlRequest.readyState + " :" + xmlRequest.status);
    if (xmlRequest.readyState ==4 || xmlRequest.status == 200)
          document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML=xmlRequest.responseText;
    };
    xmlRequest.open("POST", url, false);
    alert(xmlRequest.readyState);
    xmlRequest.send(null);
}
```

but the form is not submitting(request is not executed or no data posted).How to submit the form using Ajax.

Thanks

Comment: Why no using jquery? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @Bondye - suppose it is better when someone know the basics. Knowing about XMLHTTPRequest he will understand jquery ajax better when will switch to it. As for me - that is bad idea to suggest using jquery for newbies. user1321824 - why do you think it is not posted? request is not executed or no data posted?

Comment: @FAngel: Couldn't agree more: No jQuery tag, no jQuery... pure JS knowledge is a wonderful thing. Many jQ-fanatics would fare well with a better understanding of how JS works

Comment: @FAngel It is a question/advice, not an answer.

Comment: @Bondye I don't see anywhere the above users suggested you were giving it as an answer.

Comment: I totally agree that people need to learn more about JS (for example == in this example) however getting Ajax calls which are cross browser is just a pain, and I'd suggest JQ to fill in for that issue.

Comment: Anyway on to the question: if this code is not getting executed the problem is outside of this can you include the HTML (or relevant parts) which should be calling this ?

Comment: `I don't see anywhere the above users suggested you were giving it as an answer.` Anyone can translate this?

Comment: The two users above your last reply..  FAngel, Elias; neither suggested the comment you gave was an answer, as you suggested.

Answer (score 4):

There's a few reasons why your code doesn't work. Allow me to break it down and go over the issues one by one. I'll start of with the last (but biggest) problem:

```
xmlRequest.send(null);
```

My guess is, you've based your code on a `GET` example, where the send method is called with `null`, or even `undefined` as a parameter (`xhr.send()`). This is because the url contains the data in a GET request (`.php?param1=val1&param2=val2...`). When using post, you're going to *have* to pass the data to the send method.

But Let's not get ahead of ourselves:

```
function persistPage(divID,url,method)
{   
    var scriptId = "inlineScript_" + divID;
    var xmlRequest = getXMLHttpRequest();//be advised, older IE's don't support this
    xmlRequest.open("POST",url,true);
    //Set additional headers:
    xmlRequest.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');//marks ajax request
    xmlRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencode');//sending form
```

The first of the two headers is not always a necessity, but it's better to be safe than sorry, IMO. Now, onward:

```
    xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        alert(xmlRequest.readyState + " :" + xmlRequest.status);
        if (xmlRequest.readyState ==4 || xmlRequest.status == 200)
            document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML=xmlRequest.responseText;
    };
```

This code has a number of issues. You're assigning a method to an object, so there's no need to refer to your object using `xmlRequest`, though technically valid here, this will break once you move the callback function outside the `persistPage` function. The `xmlRequest` variable is local to the function's scope, and cannot be accessed outside it. Besides, as I said before, it's a method: `this` points to the object directly
Your `if` statement is a bit weird, too: the `readystate` *must* be 4, **and** status == 200, not or. So:

```
    xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        alert(this.readyState + " :" + this.status);
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200)
        {
            document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML=this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlRequest.open("POST", url, false);
    alert(xmlRequest.readyState);//pointless --> ajax is async, so it will alert 0, I think
    xmlRequest.send(data);//<-- data goes here
}
```

How you fill the data is up to you, but make sure the format matches the header: in this case `'content type','x-www-form-urlencode'`. [Here's a full example of just such a request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534441/javascript-ajax-request-vs-jquery-ajax), it's not exactly a world beater, since I was in the process of ditching jQ in favour of pure JS at the time, but it's serviceable and you might pick up a thing or two. Especially take a closer look at `function ajax()` definition. In it you'll see a X-browser way to create an xhr-object, and there's a function in there to stringify forms, too

---

*POINTLESS UPDATE:*

Just for completeness sake, I'll add a full example:

```
function getXhr()
{
    try
    {
        return XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (error)
    {
        try
        {
            return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
        }
        catch(error)
        {
            try
            {
                return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            }
            catch(error)
            {
                //throw new Error('no Ajax support?');
                            alert('You have a hopelessly outdated browser');
                            location.href = 'http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/';
            }
        }
    }
}
function formalizeObject(form)
{//we'll use this to create our send-data
    recursion = recursion || false;
    if (typeof form !== 'object')
    {
        throw new Error('no object provided');
    }
    var ret = '';
    form = form.elements || form;//double check for elements node-list
    for (var i=0;i<form.length;i++)
    {
        if (form[i].type === 'checkbox' || form[i].type === 'radio')
        {
            if (form[i].checked)
            {
                ret += (ret.length ? '&' : '') + form[i].name + '=' + form[i].value;
            }
            continue;
        }
        ret += (ret.length ? '&' : '') + form[i].name +'='+ form[i].value; 
    }
    return encodeURI(ret);
}

function persistPage(divID,url,method)
{   
    var scriptId = "inlineScript_" + divID;
    var xmlRequest = getXhr();
    xmlRequest.open("POST",url,true);
    xmlRequest.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    xmlRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencode');
    xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        alert(this.readyState + " :" + this.status);
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200)
        {
            document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML=this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlRequest.open("POST", url, false);
    alert(xmlRequest.readyState);
    xmlRequest.send(formalizeObject(document.getElementById('formId').elements));
}
```

Just for fun: this code, untested, but should work allright. Though, on each request the `persistPage` will create a new function object and assign it to the `onreadystate` event of `xmlRequest`. You could write this code so that you'll only need to create 1 function. I'm not going into my beloved closures right now (I think you have enough on your plate with this), but it's important to know that functions are objects, and have properties, just like everything else:
Replace:

```
    xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        alert(this.readyState + " :" + this.status);
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200)
        {
            document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML=this.responseText;
        }
    };
```

With this:

```
//inside persistPage function:
xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = formSubmitSuccess;
formSubmitSuccess.divID = divID;//<== assign property to function
//global scope
function formSubmitSuccess()
{
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200)
    {
        console.log(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById(formSubmitSuccess.divID).innerHTML = this.responseText;
        //^^ uses property, set in persistPAge function
    }
}
```

Don't use this though, as async calls could still be running while you're reassigning the property, causing mayhem. If the id is always going to be the same, you can, though (but closures would be even better, then).

Ok, I'll leave it at that

Answer (score 0):

This code can let you understand. The function **SendRequest** send the request and build the **xmlRequest** through the **GetXMLHttpRequest** function

```
function SendRequest() {
    var xmlRequest = GetXMLHttpRequest(),
    if(xmlRequest) {

        xmlRequest.open("POST", '/urlToPost', true)

        xmlRequest.setRequestHeader("connection", "close");
        xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlRequest.status == 200) {
                // Success          
            }
            else {
                // Some errors occured                  
            }               
        };

        xmlRequest.send(null);
    }
}

function GetXMLHttpRequest() {
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != (-1)) {
        var theClass = "Msxml2.XMLHTTP";
            if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 5.5") != (-1)) {
            theClass = "Microsoft.XMLHTTP";
        }
        try {
            objectXMLHTTP = new ActivexObject(theClass);
            return objectXMLHTTP;
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert("Errore: the Activex will not be executed!");
        }
    }
    else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mozilla") != (-1)) {
        objectXMLHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
        return objectXMLHTTP;
    }
    else {
        alert("!Browser not supported!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/xmlhttp.html) page. In this line: `req.send(postData);` post data is an array with values that should be posted to server. You have null there. so nothing is posted. You just call request and send no data. In your case you must collect all values from your form, as XMLHTTPRequest is not something that can simply submit form. You must pass all values with JS:

```
   var postData = {};
   postData.value1 = document.getElementById("value1id").value;
   ...
   xmlRequest.send(postData);
```

Where `value1` will be available on server like $_POST['value'] (in PHP)

Also there might be a problem with URL or how you are calling `persistPage`. persistPage code looks ok to me, but maybe I'm missing something. Also you can take a look if you have no errors in console. Press F12 in any browser and find console tab. In FF you may need to install Firebug extention. Also there you will have Network tab with all requests. Open Firebug/Web Inspector(Chrome)/Developer Toolbar(IE) and check if new request is registered in its network tab after you call persistPage.

Answer (score 0):

I found you've invoked the

> xmlRequest.open()

method twice, one with async param as true and the other as false. What exactly do you intend to do?

```
xmlRequest.open("POST", url, true);
...
xmlRequest.open("POST", url, false);
```

If you want to send asynchronous request, pls pass the param as true.
And also, to use 'POST' method, you'd better send the request header as suggested by Elias,

```
xmlRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencode');
```

Otherwise, you may still get unexpected issues.

If you want a synchronous request, actually you may handle the response directly right after you send the request, just like:

```
xmlRequest.open("POST", url, false);
xmlRequest.send(postData);
// handle response here
document.getElementById(scriptId).innerHTML = xmlRequest.responseText;
```

Hope this helps.