# Is there a possibility to use POST in an Ajax call instead of GET (Only Javascript solution)

Tags: javascript, ajax

In this JavaScript example and all of what i could found in the web:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

The JavaScript example codes using always `GET`...

I know JQuery can simplicate things very much, and i know it can be a one liner with JQuery, but probably i do not want to use JQuery for this (because of the size overhead of jquery.js)

So the question is easy, is there an option to use `POST` vs `GET`? 
(POST has a lot more advantages than GET)
And if so, why would anybody use GET?

Comment: Don't you mention the `GET` in your `xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);` command?

Comment: @Amberlamps:Seems trivial after answers, i wasn't sure that only a single line change can do the job... And has not now option to try it, so i asked... Sorry if it is disturbed you...

Comment: @czupe: Alright, I mean you went through all the effort to create and write a question, when all you needed is typing `ajax get post` into google.

Comment: Most of these answers related to JQuery : S and i needed JS.
But you have right i could get the answer for my second question... Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. See [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/). (I don't post code because I think you can handle it yourself changing 'GET' to 'POST' ...)

Why would you use GET? Because of [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) issues (JSONP = GET) or because you using a very strict REST metapher where POST is only create, GET is receiving, PUT is updating, and DELETE is used to remove items.

Comment: accepted this (because you answered my other question is, appreciate it) and upvoted all answers. Thanks all!

Comment: @czupe don't want to be rude but you didn't ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Use `xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax_info.txt",true);`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is... [here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534441/javascript-ajax-request-vs-jquery-ajax)

Basically, you'll have to open the connection like so:

```
xmlhttp.open('post','script/url',true);
xmlhttp.send('data=foo&bar=foobar');//data here
```

Of course, you'll best set a couple of headers:

```
xmlhttp.open('post','script/ur',true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200)
    {
        console.log(this.responseText);//do whatever
    }
};
xmlhttp.send('data=foo&bar=foobar');//data here
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is,

```
var r = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
r.open("POST", "path/to/api", true); 
r.onreadystatechange = function () { 
   if (r.readyState != 4 || r.status != 200) 
      return; 

    alert("Success: " + r.responseText); 
}; 
r.send("banana=yellow");
```

Example taken from [vanilla-js](http://vanilla-js.com/). Use vanillajs, it is only 0kb and free :)

Comment: vanillajs isn't a toolkit, lib or framework... it's just pure JavaScript (browser implementation, with DOM api). The documentation link just links to MDN