# Post a Form to a PHP File using XMLHTTPRequest/AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am a bit forgetful of PHP, is there a simpler way to post a form using JavaScript AJAX, don't want to add jQuery simply to post an ajax request, without having to pass the parameters?

I want to post the form via Ajax and not have to get the parameters  and send them in the call, is this possible? Is there an alternative to the following code...

```
var mypostrequest=new ajaxRequest()
mypostrequest.onreadystatechange=function(){
 if (mypostrequest.readyState==4){
  if (mypostrequest.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1){
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=mypostrequest.responseText
  }
  else{
   alert("An error has occured making the request")
  }
 }
}
var namevalue=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("name").value)
var agevalue=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("age").value)
var parameters="name="+namevalue+"&age="+agevalue
mypostrequest.open("POST", "basicform.php", true)
mypostrequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
**mypostrequest.send(parameters)**
```

It is my intent to use POST instead of GET to hide what is being sent on the URL, this feels strange and it's the same as using a GET. Or am I reading this wrong?

Comment: I know you said you don't want to add jQuery just for this, but it really would be worth adding jQuery, even just for this. In short, without adding jQuery there is no simple way to do this.

Comment: jQuery makes this sooo much easier

Comment: http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif from here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question

Comment: @Pinoniq not really applicable here... You don't reinvent the wheel when someone has already done it for you.

Comment: @Styphon exactly. now tell me what reinventing the wheel is when using 'new XMLHttpRequest()' ?

Comment: Don't really want to use jQuery, I use it when I have to, but this is a simple page to submit a form, get a reply from php and put it on screen. I don't need to use selectors, or anything fancy... pure JS should do it.

Comment: The reason why I want to do post is to hide what I am sending, this way defeats the purpose of using POST

Comment: @Pinoniq when a library is built to do it for you, it's reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @Styphon indeex, XMLHttpRequest does everything for me. So why re-invent the wheel so it fits into the rest of the library?

Comment: [Check my question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534441/javascript-ajax-request-vs-jquery-ajax) it contains a `formailizeObject` function that you can use to stringify a form, in such a way that you can post it using AJAX requests...

Answer (score -3):

Just don't use jQuery if you only want some plain simple Ajax.

This will do the job just fine:

```
// Vanilla
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function (data) {
  // code
}
httpRequest.open('GET', url)
httpRequest.send()
```

> All kudos go to: https://gist.github.com/liamcurry/2597326

Now we could also add some more browser support (IE6 and older: http://caniuse.com/#search=XMLHttpRequest) @ all those jQuery heads: jQuery 2 dropped support for IE8 and older so no 'extra support' there.

```
// creates an XMLHttpRequest instance
function createXMLHttpRequestObject()
{
  // xmlHttp will store the reference to the XMLHttpRequest object
  var xmlHttp;
  // try to instantiate the native XMLHttpRequest object
  try
  {
    // create an XMLHttpRequest object
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  catch(e)
  {
    // assume IE6 or older
    try
    {
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp");
    }
    catch(e) { }
  }
  // return the created object or display an error message
  if (!xmlHttp)
    alert("Error creating the XMLHttpRequest object.");
  else 
    return xmlHttp;
}
```

All kudos go to: http://www.cristiandarie.ro/asp-ajax/Async.html

This post was sponsored by Google (a really powerfull tool, you type in stuff and it gives more stuff with answers)

Comment: jQuery v2 may have dropped support by jQuery v1.10 still maintains it and is still developed along side v2.

Comment: I think you are missing the point. I am asking if there is a way to do an AJAX form post that does not require me to send(parameter) the parameters but instead works like a real submit button, where all my variables are in the global $_POST, I don't whant to jump to the other page I simply whant to update the same page, using GET this is very simple, and using POST it can be done in the way posted above, but I am looking for an alternative way to do this with POST.

Comment: As m59 allready pointed out, you can't do this in vanlilla js. A lot of frameworks out there have some spcial functions to help you out with serializing data (again, see m59). But hey, why -1? because I understood the question wrong?

Comment: @Pinoniq: Everything jQ does, JS does... so you _can_ do it with [VanillaJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534441/javascript-ajax-request-vs-jquery-ajax) The code in my question is a bit dodgey, but meanwhile I've perfected the form-formalizer code in my own toolkit (in total 250 lines of non-obfuscated code, ajax, event delegation, ready-callbacks and basic worker support... all in! [smug]Beat that jQ! [/smug])