# passing JavaScript value to PHP and POST it (same file)

Tags: javascript, php

I have a file called sendform.php which includes a form that POST the data and sends it by mail.

Now I have a JavaScript function that multiplies select options of 4 different select fields.

```
        <script language="javascript">
        function Calculate()
        {
            var h = document.getElementById('bedrag-bol').value;
            var l = document.getElementById('aantal-bol').value;
            var h2 = document.getElementById('bedrag-gamma').value;
            var l2 = document.getElementById('aantal-gamma').value;
            var h3 = document.getElementById('bedrag-douglas').value;
            var l3 = document.getElementById('aantal-douglas').value;
            var h4 = document.getElementById('bedrag-bartsmit').value;
            var l4 = document.getElementById('aantal-bartsmit').value;
            var result = h * l * 10 + h2 *l2 * 10 + h3 * l3 * 10 + h4 * l4 * 10;
            document.getElementById('totaal').innerHTML = result;
        }
    </script>
                    <form name="aanvraag" method="post" action="index.php?p=<?php echo $_GET['p']; ?>&amp;action=checkform">
                    <table width="700" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="bestanden/spaaractie/bol.png"  /></td>
        <td><img src="bestanden/spaaractie/gamma.png"  /></td>
        <td><img src="bestanden/spaaractie/douglas.png"  /></td>
        <td><img src="bestanden/spaaractie/bartsmit.png"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><select id="bedrag-bol" name="bedrag-bol" onChange="Calculate();">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">Kies uw bedrag</option>
                <option value="5" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['bedrag-bol']) == "5") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>&euro; 5,00</option>
                <option value="10" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['bedrag-bol']) == "10") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>&euro; 10,00</option>
                <option value="25" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['bedrag-bol']) == "25") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>&euro; 25,00</option>
                <option value="50" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['bedrag-bol']) == "50") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>&euro; 50,00</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><select id="bedrag-gamma" name="bedrag-gamma" onChange="Calculate();">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">Kies uw bedrag</option>
                <option value="5" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['bedrag-gamma']) == "5") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>&euro; 5,00</option>
                <option value="10" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['bedrag-gamma']) == "10") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>&euro; 10,00</option>
                <option value="25" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['bedrag-gamma']) == "25") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>&euro; 25,00</option>
                <option value="50" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['bedrag-gamma']) == "50") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>&euro; 50,00</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><select id="bedrag-douglas" name="bedrag-douglas" onChange="Calculate();">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">Kies uw bedrag</option>
                <option value="10" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['bedrag-douglas']) == "10") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>&euro; 10,00</option>
                <option value="25" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['bedrag-douglas']) === "25") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>&euro; 25,00</option>
                <option value="50" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['bedrag-douglas']) == "50") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>&euro; 50,00</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><select id="bedrag-bartsmit" name="bedrag-bartsmit" onChange="Calculate();">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">Kies uw bedrag</option>
                <option value="5" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['bedrag-bartsmit']) == "5") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>&euro; 5,00</option>
                <option value="10" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['bedrag-bartsmit']) === "10") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>&euro; 10,00</option>
                <option value="25" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['bedrag-bartsmit']) == "25") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>&euro; 25,00</option>
                <option value="50" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['bedrag-bartsmit']) == "50") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>&euro; 50,00</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><select id="aantal-bol" name="aantal-bol" onChange="Calculate();">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">Kies het aantal</option>
                <option value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-bol']) == "1") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>1</option>
                <option value="2" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-bol']) == "2") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>2</option>
                <option value="3" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-bol']) == "3") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>3</option>
                <option value="4" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-bol']) == "4") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>4</option>
                <option value="5" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-bol']) == "5") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>5</option>
                <option value="6" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-bol']) == "6") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>6</option>
                <option value="7" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-bol']) == "7") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>7</option>
                <option value="8" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-bol']) == "8") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>8</option>
                <option value="9" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-bol']) == "9") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>9</option>
                <option value="10" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-bol']) == "10") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>10</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><select id="aantal-gamma" name="aantal-gamma" onChange="Calculate();">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">Kies het aantal</option>
                <option value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-gamma']) == "1") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>1</option>
                <option value="2" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-gamma']) == "2") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>2</option>
                <option value="3" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-gamma']) == "3") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>3</option>
                <option value="4" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-gamma']) == "4") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>4</option>
                <option value="5" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-gamma']) == "5") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>5</option>
                <option value="6" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-gamma']) == "6") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>6</option>
                <option value="7" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-gamma']) == "7") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>7</option>
                <option value="8" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-gamma']) == "8") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>8</option>
                <option value="9" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-gamma']) == "9") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>9</option>
                <option value="10" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-gamma']) == "10") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>10</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><select id="aantal-douglas" name="aantal-douglas" onChange="Calculate();">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">Kies het aantal</option>
                <option value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-douglas']) == "1") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>1</option>
                <option value="2" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-douglas']) == "2") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>2</option>
                <option value="3" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-douglas']) == "3") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>3</option>
                <option value="4" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-douglas']) == "4") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>4</option>
                <option value="5" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-douglas']) == "5") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>5</option>
                <option value="6" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-douglas']) == "6") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>6</option>
                <option value="7" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-douglas']) == "7") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>7</option>
                <option value="8" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-douglas']) == "8") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>8</option>
                <option value="9" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-douglas']) == "9") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>9</option>
                <option value="10" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-douglas']) == "10") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>10</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><select id="aantal-bartsmit" name="aantal-bartsmit" onChange="Calculate();">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">Kies het aantal</option>
                <option value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-bartsmit']) == "1") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>1</option>
                <option value="2" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-bartsmit']) == "2") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>2</option>
                <option value="3" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-bartsmit']) == "3") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>3</option>
                <option value="4" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-bartsmit']) == "4") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>4</option>
                <option value="5" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-bartsmit']) == "5") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>5</option>
                <option value="6" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-bartsmit']) == "6") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>6</option>
                <option value="7" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-bartsmit']) == "7") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>7</option>
                <option value="8" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-bartsmit']) == "8") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>8</option>
                <option value="9" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-bartsmit']) == "9") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>9</option>
                <option value="10" <?php if(isset($_POST['Submitform']) && strip_tags($_POST['aantal-bartsmit']) == "10") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>10</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div style="margin-left:15px; margin-top:20px;"><span id="totaal" style="color:#F00;">0</span></div>
                        
                        <div id="fm-submit">
                            <input name="Submitform" value="Verstuur" type="submit" />
                        </div>
                

</form>
```

Is it possible to POST the JavaScript variable with PHP? I found some articles about it and I know it is possible but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Did you see the term AJAX, by any chance? [here's a rather elaborate example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534441/javascript-ajax-request-vs-jquery-ajax) but google _"XMLHttpRequest AJAX tutorial"_

Comment: Ajax isn't required to do this. You could also have a `<input type="hidden">` and update its `.value`. If you want to pass anything else than a string have a look at JSON.

Comment: @Christoph: AJAX isn't required here (didn't read the question properly), but I'm not too big on hidden fields. Perhaps change the value attribute on the change event might be better still?

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with using hidden fields. Once the value is filled in with JS, the form can be submitted “normally” without any extra efforts necessary, and the server-side script can access the value like any other POST parameter … it doesn’t get any easier than this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for al the reply's

This did the trick:

Javascript:

```
document.aanvraag.totaal.value = result; //assign value to hidden input element.
```

Html

```
<input type="hidden" name="totaal" id="totaal" value="" />
```

@Christoph Thank you!:)

Answer (score 0):

**See Form**

```
 <form name="aanvraag" method="post" action="" onsubmit="Calculate()">
```

Write your all HTML HERE and include hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" name="totaal" id="totaal" value="" />

<input name="Submitform" value="Verstuur" type="submit" />

</form>
```

**When you submit this form then before submit the form calculate function will call and it paste 
total value in hidden field and then all value post with your given URL.**